# How can i apply such an effect to an image dynamically in .net?

Tags: asp.net, image, 3d

So I want to create thumbnails of images uploaded in my asp.net applications to look like this. I intend to generate the thumbnail at the time of upload. Whats the simplest approach to do this?

[image]

Comment: You mean to apply a rectangular flat photo, to a "3d model" ?

Comment: Yeah. I have a flat square photo. I want it wrapped on the front side of a black rectangular box, apply a perspective transform, add shadows/lights effect etc..

Comment: You seem to have a pretty good idea of how to do it. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I know how to do this in OpenGl. I am looking for someone to point me in right direction for doing it for a web app. Libraries/tools I can use etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it :

Use your favorite image editor to create a "template" image, containing white background, box side and shadow.

When an image is uploaded to your website (or whatever), use `System.Drawing` namespace to do the following :

- Load your template image
- Load the uploaded image
- Draw the uploaded image on the template image with the appropriate transform matrix
- Save the resulting image/thumbnail